# User Permissions

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I've been using CiviCRM on Wordpress for about a year now. Initially, I had created a user who had 'viewing' permissions only, although this user has not been active. I'm trying to use it now and whenever I try to view a contact's details I get this error: `DB error: no such table`. Any advice?

I have checked the Wordpress security profile and everything looks ok and this user does not have any additional CIvi ACLs assigned.
Thanks for your insight into this!

Comment: can you paste the error & backtrace generated in ConfigAndLog file ?

Comment: From CIVI screen:
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
DB Error: no such table

Return to home page.

Comment: My IT guy is not in yet and I don't know where to find the ConfigAndLog file. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: sure ConfigAndLog File would be created at `<wp_folder>/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/your_log_file.`

Comment: Sorry for my limited knowledge here... I found the ConfigAndLog folder and there are about 6 files in there, non of which I recognize the file type except for a text file and the most recent one is dated about a year ago. Wouldn't/shouldn't there be a more recent one if it's actively logging my errors?

Comment: Ok, I have the backtrace...just trying to figure out how to chop it up to post it. It's too long to post in here. Thank you for your help and patience @jitendrapurohit

Comment: Database Error Code: Table 'civi_crm.civicrm_acl' doesn't exist, 1146
Additional Details:

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -18
    [message] => DB Error: no such table
    [mode] => 16[debug_info] =>  SELECT      civicrm_acl.*
                        FROM        civicrm_acl  WHERE   civicrm_acl.entity_table   = 'civicrm_contact'
                            AND     civicrm_acl.entity_id      = 8218 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'civi_crm.civicrm_acl' doesn't exist]

Comment: [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] =>  SELECT      civicrm_acl.*
                        FROM        civicrm_acl  WHERE   civicrm_acl.entity_table   = 'civicrm_contact'
                            AND     civicrm_acl.entity_id      = 8218 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'civi_crm.civicrm_acl' doesn't exist]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info=" SELECT      civicrm_acl.*

Comment: FROM        civicrm_acl  WHERE   civicrm_acl.entity_table   = 'civicrm_contact'
                            AND     civicrm_acl.entity_id      = 8218 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'civi_crm.civicrm_acl' doesn't exist]"]
)

Comment: I also got a long error when I was trying to add a new user on the Wordpress side. I'm getting the feeling that we are going to have to do a major reinstall and restore...

Answer (score 2):

You're missing one of your tables in the CiviCRM database.  I'm not sure how that could have possibly happened!  I don't think it's possible for CiviCRM to have done it.

If you have a backup, your IT person may be able to restore just the `civicrm_acl` table - assuming that's the only one that's missing!  If there's no backup, there's a file `<civicrm_root>/sql/civicrm.mysql`.  Someone can open it up in a text editor, search for the "paragraph" starting with "

```
CREATE TABLE `civicrm_acl` (
```

and run that entire command in MySQL to recreate a blank ACL table.

Finally - thank you for posting the backtrace, it's what allowed me to figure out your problem!  The best way to post it is to edit your original question, which allows you better formatting options.

Comment: Thank you so so much!!! I will work on it as soon as my IT guy gets in and let you know how it goes. :)